# <apex:chart> bar chart with annotated bars

Tags: visualforce, charts

Is it possible to annotate bars on an `<apex:chart>` something like this:

[image: bar chart]

Charts already have hover help which shows this value. I just want to make it so the user doesn't need to hover and read each individual bar value.

Comment: There is `renderFn` available in [apex:barSeries](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_barSeries.htm) that in theory would allow you to write some JavaScript to display the numbers. But AFAIK there is no documentation on the objects passed to that function and so unless you can find an example somewhere you would need to use a JavaScript debugger and Google to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the chartLabel tag

see https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_chartLabel.htm for an example

Comment: While this answer is correct, SFSE community practice would be for the answer to include an illustrative code snippet as the link you included does not show an example for annotating a data series.